# Differing Trailing PE Ratios Yahoo Finance and Reuters and Industry PE

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, yahoo-finance, financial-statements

For example, consider XRX. Is the differing PE Ratio of  between Reuters and Yahoo Finance simply because one made a mistake?

Ideally, I'd like Reuters' answer to be correct since they display industry PE Ratio. Does Yahoo Finance display Industry PE Ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that XRX just released their financials today (10/23), I suspect that one site has updated their ratios based on the latest financials and the other has not.

In any case, you'd have to look at the raw financial statements for the last 4 quarters and see how both sites have "normalized" them to be comparable. Different services can normalize in different ways, so it's not uncommon to see differences due to that alone.

Comment: Thank you, guess you can't really compare same companies using Reuters and Yahoo then.

Comment: It's easier to compare companies within the same platform. When you use different platforms you have to know how they normalize data differently.